# What are the purposes for all of the distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, big-list

I want a list of all of the main distributions and their application:
Example entry:

Poisson$(\lambda)$ - Models number of events in a given amount of time or space.

Thank you, community answer would likely be optimal?

Comment: Downvote, on a biglist? Someone please explain that to me.

Comment: I guess the problem (reason for downvote) is lack of research.

Comment: I have done much research but was surprised math stack exchange was so lacking

Comment: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) would be the first place to check as per google.

Comment: Still not good I can't find the mathematical equation for the relevant distributions. I just want it to all be easier

Comment: If you had wanted the expressions for the probability density functions or for the cumulative density functions, you should have mentioned that in your question.  I would recommend typing what you see in the lists of distributions at the links I gave below into Wolfram Alpha, since it will give you these.  Examples :  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bernoulli+distribution&dataset=  and  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PDF[BernoulliDistribution[p],x]&dataset=&asynchronous=false&equal=Submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conveniently, this has already been done.

Continuous:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ContinuousDistributions.html

Discrete:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiscreteDistributions.html

Comment: This doesn't explain when to use them, so inconveniently it isn't applicable.

Comment: @Katie: You have failed to read the text.  Every distribution is explained in at least as much detail as you gave for the Poisson distribution.  In fact, your description is nearly identical to the one at the cited pages.